# Site.changePassword returns null when called using javascript remoting

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting, customer-community

My Use case is:
As a CustomerCommunity user, I want to login and click on change_password link that redirects me to change_password page in AngularJs, which calles the changePassword method using javascript remoting, so that I can change my password.
Issue:
This method returns pageReference as null.
this is my code:
Visualforce Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="CustomCommunitiesLandingController" docType="html-5.0">
    <script>
     function  chgPwd() {
       var newPassword = document.getElementById('newPwd').value;
       var verifyNewPassword = document.getElementById('verPwd').value;
       var oldPassword = document.getElementById('oldPwd').value;
         Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
         '{!$RemoteAction.CustomCommunitiesLandingController.changePassword}',newPassword,verifyNewPassword,oldPassword,
         function(result, event) {
           alert("result");

         });
         } 
    </script>
     <div class="bootstrap"  >
    oldPwd <input type="text" id='oldPwd' />
     newpwd<input type="text" id='newPwd' />
     verpwd<input type="text" id='verPwd' />
     <h1 align="center">Click The Button</h1>
     <button onClick="chgPwd()" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block">change password</button> 
     </div>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller Method:

```
    @remoteAction
    public static String changePassword(string newPassword, string verifyNewPassword, string oldPassword){
    pageReference pr;
    string success;
    pr = Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword);
    if(pr != null){
        success = 'true';
    }else {
        success = 'false';
    }
    return success;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Devayani

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods of the [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) class are designed to work from Visualforce and within a Site so it is possible that the call can't be made to work in your situation. If the context was Visualforce, errors would be available in the `ApexPages.getMessages()` collection and you could convert them into some other format for your response (e.g. an error string response for a failure and `null` or an empty string response for success):

```
for (ApexPages.Message m : ApexPages.getMessages()) {
    // Add messages to your response string
}
```

but that `ApexPages.getMessages()` call may not work at all in a `@RemoteAction`. Try it and see.

In an Angular app that I wrote, I ended up using separate Visualforce pages for calls like this one (separate from the main Angular Visualforce page) which was not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Site.changePassword does not work in Apex REST service too